# 404 when attempting to change ownership of a file owned by deleted user

Tags: google-drive-api

**Scenario**

- Goal: I desire to delete a file in Drive.
- Complication: Said file is owned by a long deleted account and cannot be trashed through the web UI.
- Solution: Change ownership of the file so that an active user can delete the file. Per [documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1247799?hl=en) it seems the only option is to use the Drive API to execute [an ownership change via update operation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) as an administrator (me).
- Problem: When executing the ownership change via API Explorer interface I receive a generic 404 file not found error. However, other API calls on the very same file ID succeed without issue.
- Conclusion: The 404 error is due to an undocumented error case rather than related to the actual existence of the file — either the operation cannot occur when the original owner no longer exists, or I'm using the wrong combination of payload and options for this scenario.

**Questions**

1. Is it possible to change ownership (or delete) a file owned by a deleted user by API? If so, how?
2. If my approach via the API update operation is, in fact, possible, what does the 404 error indicate? What is the correct payload and options to submit through the API Explorer to successfully change ownership?

Comment: Have you checked this post by the [G Suite Administrator support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1247799?hl=en)?

Comment: Indeed I have. In fact, the first link in my post here is to that very same post. Since the owner of the file is a deleted account, it appears my only option is using the update API. But, when I do, I get a 404 error despite other API calls succeeding for the very same file ID (i.e. the file _is_ found).